# Update Draft on-the-go in with outlook addin

Tags: javascript, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, outlook-web-addins

I am working on  a outlook add-in. I want to be **able to update the draft with a data on the go** (body of email converted to encrypted format.). The goal is to protect the data of user , so that the orignal data is not stored in draft as the person is writing in compose mode.
I am using office.js(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/apis). But i am not able to update draft using it , also cannot access attachment in read mode.
What could be a possible approch. Can i use Microsoft graph? or any suggestion how to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to update compose mails with any of the following apis:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messagecompose?view=outlook-js-preview

You can access attachments in Read Mode Via the Attachment APIs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#attachments

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.messageread?view=outlook-js-preview#getAttachmentContentAsync_attachmentId__callback_

Comment: Is there any way by which i can stop draft from updating as i the user writes mail. I want the message being written by user shouldnt be stored in draft (When the person writes in compose mode, a draft keeps updating with what the person is writing.)

Comment: Currently, the feature to not update drafts that you requested is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our Tech Community Page. Please submit your request there and choose the appropriate label(s). Feature requests on Tech Community are considered, when we go through our planning process.

Github Label: “Type: product feature request”
aka.ms/M365dev-suggestions